# multiple nodedown messages in erlang cluster

Tags: erlang

I am building a simple gen_server module which monitors activity of multiple remote nodes

When a remote node registers, this module monitors the node with erlang:monitor_node(Node, true). This is registered only once per node (confirmed with logs)

and in a handle_info/2 callback of gen_server, it catches {nodedown, Node} message and demonitors the node with erlang:monitor_node(Node, false). I expect to receive this message only once: when the remote node is down.

When I was testing the module, I found that when a remote node goes down, hundreds of {nodedown, Node} messages (the number varies from few hundreds to few thousands) are sent to the gen_server.

Why are multiple messages sent by monitor_node? How can I prevent this behaviour?

EDIT: here is (a part of) the source code

```
register_node(#node_info{node = NodeName} = NodeInfo) ->
    case mnesia:read(node_info, NodeName) of
        [] ->
            monitor_node(NodeName, true),
            error_logger:info_msg("node ~p registered", [NodeName]);
        [_OldInfo] ->
            error_logger:trace_msg("info of node ~p updated", [NodeName])
    end,
    mnesia:write(NodeInfo).

handle_cast({register_node, #node_info{} = NodeStatus}, Timer) ->
    case mnesia:transaction(fun register_node/1, [NodeStatus]) of
        {aborted, Reason} ->
            error_logger:warning_msg("transaction register_node failed: ~p", [Reason]);
        _ ->
        ok
    end,
    {noreply, Timer};
handle_cast({shutdown_node, #node_info{} = NodeStatus}, Timer) ->
    case mnesia:dirty_delete_object(NodeStatus) of
        {aborted, Reason} ->
            error_logger:warning_msg("transaction shutdown_node failed: ~p", [Reason]);
        _ ->
        ok
    end,
    {noreply, Timer};
handle_cast(Message, Timer) ->
    error_logger:warning_msg("~p: received unknown message ~p", [?MODULE, Message]),
    {noreply, Timer}.

handle_info({nodedown, Node}, Timer) ->
    monitor_node(Node, false),
    error_logger:info_msg("~p: node ~p down", [?MODULE, Node]),
    mnesia:transaction(fun mnesia:delete/3, [node_info, Node, write]),
    {noreply, Timer};
handle_info(Message, Timer) ->
    error_logger:warning_msg("~p: received unknown message ~p", [?MODULE, Message]),
    {noreply, Timer}.
```

Comment: Please post your source code here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have done `monitor_node(NodeName, true)` `**INSIDE**` the mnesia transaction.

I think that because monitor_node will involve (I/O operation) message communication internally. 
It is not suitable to put this line inside transation. It maybe send handreds of `'registered'` message to the involved node. So that when the node became down, handreds of `'nodedown'` messages have been received.

```
    If a process has made two calls to monitor_node(Node, true) and Node terminates, 
**two nodedown messages are delivered to the process.** If there is no connection 
to Node, there will be an attempt to create one. If this fails, a nodedown 
message is delivered.
```

Please move the line out of `transaction` or just use `"CASE"` expression, and try again.

```
register_node(#node_info{node = NodeName} = NodeInfo) ->
    case mnesia:read(node_info, NodeName) of
        [] ->
            monitor_node(NodeName, true),
            error_logger:info_msg("node ~p registered", [NodeName]);
        [_OldInfo] ->
            error_logger:trace_msg("info of node ~p updated", [NodeName])
    end,
    mnesia:write(NodeInfo).
handle_cast({register_node, #node_info{} = NodeStatus}, Timer) ->
    case mnesia:transaction(fun register_node/1, [NodeStatus]) of
        {aborted, Reason} ->
            error_logger:warning_msg("transaction register_node failed: ~p", [Reason]);
        _ ->
        ok
    end,
    {noreply, Timer};
```

[explanation of side-effect in mnesia transaction](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/mnesia/Mnesia_chap4.html)

> Mnesia dynamically sets and releases locks as transactions execute,
>   therefore, it is very dangerous to execute code with transaction
>   side-effects. In particular, a **receive statement** inside a transaction
>   can lead to a situation where the transaction hangs and never returns,
>   **which in turn can cause locks not to release**. This situation could
>   bring the whole system to a standstill since other transactions which
>   execute in other processes, or on other nodes, are forced to wait for
>   the defective transaction.

Comment: Yes, you should not do anything which has side-effects inside a mnesia transaction as you have no control or knowledge of how many times the transaction is attempted before it succeeds.

Comment: Thank you. That explains a lot. I have one more question. Does that mean I have to remove other non-pure operations out of transaction? (like I/O)

Comment: According to "rvirding"'s keyword of "side effect", I have googled it. The related information has been inserted into the above post.

Comment: @chen-yu Oh, being too lazy to thoroughly read the documentation bites me back... Thank you for your help.